# Get name of Executable Jar from code in another generic jar

Tags: java, executable-jar

I am creating a generic Java jar with a main function.  The jar itself is not to be executed, but other jars will use it and name the main inside the generic jar as their default main.  This will allow me to produce a common interface for a set of jars designed for relatively the same purpose.

My problem comes when I try to write a usage statement.  I want the usage statement to name the jar that is being called from the command line. However, I can't find a way to discover the name of the head jar being executed from my my generic Java code.

Any ideas?

Comment: R u facing issue to run the jar ??

Comment: You could try looking in the stack-trace (`Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`) to see what is calling your (main) method.